# Can't install scipy on windows

Tags: python, numpy, module, scipy

I am trying to install scipy module in python (on Windows). I am executing the following command in command line: `pip install scipy` At first it starts installing but then it give the following error:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\George\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-l2so1w7t\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8o57wqud-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\george\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l2so1w7t\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l2so1w7t\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l2so1w7t\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

I have no Idea what does it mean and have tried some things but nothing (I tried) seems to work. If it is possible please suggest the solution.

Comment: This question is asked like > 100 times here and the answer is always the same. Like the others, you missed reading the official documentation, which says: don't install scipy with pip on windows (except you know what you are doing).

Comment: Just [install Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and be done with it.

Comment: @saintsfan342000 That seems like a good solution but thing is, I am trying courses in python and some of them are 3.* and some 2.* so I constantly have to change the version which is pretty tiresome with anaconda.

Comment: @Banned I have never personally tried it, but [according to official documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html) it appears to be quite simple.  I have used conda environments for other purposes and they are very convenient.  In any case, I don't mean to argue with you, just pointing out other options.  Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Using anaconda, switching between versions is just a ```activate py2```, which changes all your environment-vars, so that python, pip and co. are actually the ones of py2. It can't be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says you are missing some dependencies. Try installing from one of these prebuilt binaries for windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Download the .whl file appropriate for your version of python then run `pip install <package_name>.whl`

Comment: It says that scipy is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Make sure you select the correct file for your python version. If you're using python 3.5.x with a 32 bit version of the interpreter (the default python install is 32 bit) then you need this one: scipy‑0.19.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl

Comment: I am using 64 bit version an python 3.6 so I downloaded scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl  - this one.

Comment: Can you try this in the interpreter and post what it says? `import platform` then
`platform.architecture()`

Comment: It says 32 Bits but (Man I'm really confused now because in System properties it's written 64 bit operating system)

Comment: Yes the interpreter version is 32 bit so you need to install using the 32 bit package even if you have a 64 bit os.

Comment: 64-bit OS can run 32-bit software, so a 64-bit OS does not imply anything about your python-version.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot